# Friend Status FQL

Tags: facebook, api, facebook-fql

I am attempting to pull the most recent 50 status updates by friends from Facebook using FQL, but it appears the status table nor the feed table work as expected.  I am using the following query, but it's results are only the updates since the last Friday @ midnight EST (i.e. at the time of this post 12/07/12 @ 12AM EST) which is not enough for my need.

`SELECT post_id,actor_id,target_id,message,created_time FROM stream WHERE source_id IN (SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1 = me()) AND filter_key = "nf" AND created_time > 1 AND type = 46 ORDER BY created_time DESC LIMIT 50`

Is there another way to get the most recent 50 status updates from friends that I can use?  I have tried the status table, but there are even less results in it.

Answer (score 0):

From http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/stream :

> Each query of the stream table is limited to the previous 30 days or 50 posts, whichever is greater, however you can use time-specific fields such as created_time along with FQL operators (such as < or >) to retrieve a much greater range of posts.

Comment: I saw that, and wish it were true.  If you try to run my query, even without the "> 1" filter, you will see that you won't have any results before last Friday.

Answer (score 0):

Try the status table

`SELECT message, status_id, uid FROM status WHERE uid IN (SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1 = me()) ORDER BY time DESC LIMIT 50`

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
SELECT message, status_id, uid FROM status WHERE uid IN
        (SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1 = me()) 
ORDER BY time DESC LIMIT 50
```

but be sure to have the friend permissons messege right ;)